# Azure Powershell cmd-let - Get-AzureRmLog doesn't show "Microsoft.Authorization/" logs

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I have prepared Azure PowerShell script for catching RBAC changes information from Azure Activity Logs. When I am testing this script on my test subscription, script works fine. Problem is when I used `connect-azurermaccount -subscription` command and switched to the prod subscription. In the Azure activity log blade I saw that there were some logs related to RBAC changes, log names like "Create role assignment". I was testing with commands like below:

```
Get-AzureRmLog -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) | 
Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -like 
"Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/*"}
```

and

```
Get-AzureRmLog -StartTime 2019-09-01T10:30 | Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -like "*Microsoft.Authorization/*"}
```

I didnt see any output in the console. When I logged to the Azure portal and opened Activity log I was able to see logs related to RBAC changes, log names --> "Delete role assignment", "Create role assignment". I was testing mentioned commands with string "Microsoft.Compute":

```
Get-AzureRmLog -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) | 
Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -like 
""*Microsoft.Compute/*""}
```

and

```
Get-AzureRmLog -StartTime 2019-09-01T10:30 | Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -like "*Microsoft.Compute/*"}`
```

I could see the logs information in the output. I am not sure what is wrong and what should I correct. Why can't I use this filter in my prod subscription --> "*Microsoft.Authorization/*", I would like to highlight that on my test subscription script worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the logs related to RBAC changes, you can use the following the script to get it.

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount

Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceProvider Microsoft.Authorization -StartTime (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/get-azurermlog?view=azurermps-6.13.0

**Update**

If you want to use Azure rest api to  get the logs related to RBAC changes, you need to use the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activitylogs/list) as below:

```
Method : GET
URL:https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription id>/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values
Params:
       api-version = 2017-03-01-preview
       $filter = eventTimestamp ge 'your strat time' and resourceTypes eq 'microsoft.authorization/roleassignments'
Header:
       Authorization : Bearer access_token
```

For example:
[image]

According to my test, if the numbers of your log are too big, the results will be paged. If you want to get the other pages' results, we need to send request to the nextlink which is a parameter in the result.
[image]

Comment: Hi, it worked, but I can see now all events, for example I can see log with authorization property like --> Authorization.Action `Microsoft.Resources/checkPolicyCompliance/read`, when I want to filter out only `Microsoft.Authorization`, using following command, there is no output --> `Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceProvider Microsoft.Authorization -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-15) | 
Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -like "Microsoft.Authorization/"}`. I tested the same command on my test subscription and worked fine. What should I correct?

Comment: I corrected my command --> `Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceProvider Microsoft.Authorization -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-15) | 
Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -like "Microsoft.Authorization/*"}` - and it works. Problem is that my script is using REST API, and I would like get all this authorization info via REST API, I am using following link in my script --> `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionID/providers/microsoft.authorization/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&`$filter=$filter`, when I want to get Microsoft.Autorization logs I get empty output.

Comment: OK. I will do a test.

Comment: Hi, I have script prepared with all required variables, works ok, I am using `$output = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $request -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $authHeader`, then --> `$Output.Value | Where-Object {$_.authorization.action -like "Microsoft.Authorization/*"}`, used exact the same API REST link You suggested, but don`t see any output, if I change  "Microsoft.Authorization/*" to "Microsoft.Compute/*" i get correct output, I see logs. What is wrong with this "Microsoft.Authorization" filter?

Comment: Regarding the issue, let me do some research.

Comment: According to my test, if the numbers of logs are too big, the results will be paged and you only get the logs of the first page.  So you cannot get the logs you need. If you want to get other pages' results, you need to send a request to the nextlink url which is a paramr in your result. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activitylogs/list#eventdatacollection

Comment: I used the time filter --> `$filter="eventTimestamp ge '2019-09-11T05:27:37.6407898Z' and eventTimestamp le '2019-09-11T11:36:37.6407898Z'"`, and still have empty output. In Azure Activity logs I can see 6 logs in this period of time.

Comment: Could you please print all the results in this period of time to check if it has logs related to RBAC changes?

Comment: I decided to use command `Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceProvider Microsoft.Authorization -StartTime (Get-Date).AddHours((-5)) | 
Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -like "Microsoft.Authorization/*"}`and re-write my script, but I am not sure how to get nested property, like "PrincipalId" from this nested json property --> `properties: requestbody: {"Id":"xxx","Properties":{"PrincipalId":"xxx","RoleDefinitionId":"/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/xxx","Scope":"/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxx"}}`

Comment: According to my test, you can use the script:```$values =Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceProvider Microsoft.Authorization -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-31)  |  Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -like "*Microsoft.Authorization/*"}
 foreach($value in $values){
     $t = ConvertFrom-Json  $value.Properties.Content.Values
     $t.properties.roleDefinitionId
      $t.properties.principalId
   
 }``` to print these value